# Why I have several mount point with the same name?

Tags: mount

I have 750GB Internal Hard-Disk, with 4 partition.

One partition is for Ubuntu, Another 3 partition are only for storage.

One of my partition name was "Virtual Box". Suddenly, Partition name in sidebar shows "Virtual Box", But when i check properties of partition it shows "/media/Virtual Box2/"

[image]

And When i Go to Command line and do `ls` inside `/media/` directory. It shows below 3 partition.
[image]

And I have `Ubuntu Virtual box file` in my "Virtual Box" partition, but it says "Access Denied" for "Virtual Box1" Name there.

[image]

Kindly help me in Fixing my Partition. I am not able to open my "virtualbox" file.

Comment: Oh Thanks, Can any 'Moderator', move my question there.
Thanks

Comment: I flagged it, hopefully they will move it.

Comment: No Answers yet :(

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `ls -l` of the `/media/???/` directory. Obfuscating the file paths really isn't necessary, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we take a look to your `ls -l /media/$USER` we will make sure. But the guesses now is that you have not 1 but 2 directories called `Virtual Box` in `/media/$USER`. The easiest way to solve this is:

1. Make all directories symbolic links of `/media/$USER/Virtual Box`:

   ```
   sudo umount /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box2
   sudo umount /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box1
   sudo umount /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   mv /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box2 /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   mv /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box1 /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   ln -s /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box2 /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   ln -s /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box1 /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   ```
2. Remove the others directories and remount the drive again:

   ```
   sudo umount /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box2
   sudo umount /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box1
   sudo umount /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   rm -ri /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box2
   rm -ri /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box1
   rm -ri /media/$USER/Virtual\ Box
   ```

   Restart the system.